# Round without round function python

Tags: python, rounding

I'm new to Python and a friend challenged me with a simple question that I'm stumped on:  please build me a simple program that rounds numbers without using any mathematical operations, like ROUND. I just want to figure this out for a single decimal place - like 2.1 or 5.8 - nothing fancy with long decimal places.  I beleive that it's something like an if/then statement - if < 5 then do.....do what?  Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You have to allow *some* math. Even stringifying it, using string operations, and converting it back would require math.

Comment: `int((my_num*10)+0.5)/10.0`  or `"%0.1f" % my_num_to_round `

Answer (score 7):

How about this (where `x` is your number):

Rounding to whole numbers:

```
int(x-0.5)+1
```

Rounding to nearest tenth:

```
(int(10*x-0.5)+1) / 10.0
```

Answer (score 4):

to do it without math just use strings (it still uses math)

```
"%0.1f" % my_num_to_round
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a function that uses very little math (other than the use of a greater-than or equal comparison, the only math is that which is done by the programmer to create the `nxt_int()` function).  I believe the only limitation is that only decimals can be rounded (though there is no limit on their length).

```
input = 2.899995

def nxt_int(n): # Get the next consecutive integer from the given one
    if n == '0':
        n_out = '1'
    elif n == '1':
        n_out = '2'
    elif n == '2':
        n_out = '3'
    elif n == '3':
        n_out = '4'
    elif n == '4':
        n_out = '5'
    elif n == '5':
        n_out = '6'
    elif n == '6':
        n_out = '7'
    elif n == '7':
        n_out = '8'
    elif n == '8':
        n_out = '9'
    elif n == '9':
        n_out = '0'
    return n_out

def round(in_num):
    # Convert the number to a string
    in_num_str = str(in_num)
    # Determine if the last digit is closer to 0 or 10
    if int(in_num_str[-1]) >= 5:
        # Eliminate the decimal point
        in_num_str_split = ''.join(in_num_str.split('.'))
        # Get the length of the integer portion of the number
        int_len = len(in_num_str.split('.')[0])
        # Initialize the variables used in the loop
        out_num_str = ''
        done = False
        # Loop over all the digits except the last digit in reverse order
        for num in in_num_str_split[::-1][1:]:
            # Get the next consecutive integer
            num_nxt_int = nxt_int(num)
            # Determine if the current digit needs to be increased by one
            if (num_nxt_int == '0' or num == in_num_str_split[-2] or out_num_str[-1] == '0') and not done:
                out_num_str = out_num_str + num_nxt_int
            else:
                out_num_str = out_num_str + num
                done = True
        # Build the rounded decimal
        out_num_str = (out_num_str[::-1][:int_len] + '.' + out_num_str[::-1][int_len:]).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
    else:
        # Return all except the last digit
        out_num_str = in_num_str[:-1]
    return out_num_str

print round(input)
```